# Run SKemitter Once?

Tags: swift, sknode, skemitternode

Is there a way to only run a SKemitter one time? I have a explosion when it is colliding with another node. The problem is that the explosion happens multiple times since it hits multiple times. How would I go about only running it once time?

Answer (score 1):

SKEmitterNode can be made to stop emitting after emitting `numParticlesToEmit` if that property is set:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skemitternode/1398043-numparticlestoemit

I believe that most “explosion” type emitters should already have that property set.  However I suspect your problem is that you are adding a new SKEmitterNode each time there is a hit.

You could usee a Boolean `var wasHit = false` to track the hit state.

Then when the hit occurs, check `wasHit` before adding the emitter, and then set `wasHit` to true.